# exe created using install4j eats up all CPU after 30-40 seconds from launching

Tags: java, cpu, install4j

I have created an installer for my Java application using install4j. it is running on JDK1.6 and uses Jetty as a web server and struts2 as an MVC. The application installs just fine and an exe file is created correctly. When I launch the application by double clicking on the exe file, the application launch and starts just fine and all functionality behaves correctly. 
After about 30 to 40 seconds from launching the application, I notice that the exe process is eating almost all the CPU power (up to 99%). making it so hard to use any other application on my PC. 
This only happens on Windows XP and Vista. But when I try it on Windows 7 I do not get this problem.
The windows XP and Vista machines spec are very good (3GHZ processor with 4 GB of RAM).

I really have no idea why the exe eats up all the CPU after 30 to 40 seconds of starting the application. There are no threads, no back ground workers, no logic being processed at all. its a very simply MVC application. Matter of fact i just try open the application then wait for 30 to 40 seconds (without using it) and the CPU usage shots up high.

In the task manager I noticed that 2 processors are created, one for the exe and one for the Java processor created by the exe during launching the app. only the exe process is using 99% of CPU while the Java process is idle.

Any one face something similar? any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: Hi Motokazi, I would be really interested to see how you configured install4j for your project, is there any chance you can share the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking into the Java process using VisualVM? It's part of any JDK install. It can hook into any running Java program and sample/profile it very thoroughly.

[image: VisualVM]

Comment: Actually I did not do that. i didn't know about the VisualVM tool. I will try it out and post my findings but thanks for the pointer.